# How to make only the parent div clickable?

Tags: jquery, html

As my title explains, how can I make only the parent-div clickable?

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvas" onclick="closeCanvas()">
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function closeCanvas(){
    $("#canvas").fadeOut(300);
}
```

My issue is that when I click the "image", the function closeCanvas() is also trigged. How can I make only the parent, #canvas, triggerable?

Comment: Add this to `img`, `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"`

Comment: Also see `event bubbling`. Check [What is event bubbling and capturing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add StopPropagation to `img` that mean clicking the `img` will not pass the click event to the parent div:

```
<div id="canvas" onclick="closeCanvas()">
   <img src="image.png" onClick="event.stopPropagation()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('canvas').click(function(e){
      console.log(e);  
  });

  
});

function closeCanvas(event){
  if(event.target.id== "canvas")
    $("#canvas").fadeOut(300);
}
```

```css
#canvas{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas" onclick="closeCanvas(event)">
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```